# How to remove link from header navigation within the Astra theme for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theming

Made a wordpress website with the Astra theme and I want to remove a link from the header navigation because I only want my logo to be the link to the homepage. I haven't found any working solutions yet.

I have already looked through the backend of the theme and wordpress but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I also went through the code but that didn't get me anywhere either.

Answer (score 1):

If you could take a screenshot of the specific link element that you are trying to remove that might help me understand better your situation to I can better assist you. That said, here are a few observations that might help you achieve what you are looking for.

From my end, when I install the Astra theme locally I only see two links in the navbar (header): 1) The Brand logo link (the link to the website's home page) on the left and 2) The "Sample Page" link to the only page (the default sample page) I have in my WordPress development website.

If what you are trying to do is remove page links in the navbar (header), then it looks like to me that the free version of this theme has relatively limited customization options and by default the navbar shows your published pages as navbar links (links on header area).

So as is, I think you have two quick options:

1) Disable the menu altogether, which will leave your navbar (header) with the Brand Logo link only. You can do that in the following way:
Go to:
Appearance -> Customize -> Layout -> Header -> Primary Header
Then..
Check off "Disable Menu" checkbox option. Then press the "Publish" button at the top to save this change.
From what I can see, this basically removes the navbar links on the right and leaves the Brand logo link to the website's homepage on the left only. This sounds like what you were trying to do although I am not entirely sure that is the best solution.

2) You can also simply be mindful of the way the free version of the them works with respect to the navbar (header), which, as I mentioned above, seems to display your published pages as navbar links. With that in mind, you should be able to influence what gets displayed as your navbar (header) links by adding/changing/removing your PAGES through the "Pages" from your WordPress Admin Dashboard menu. For example, in my case, if I wanted to remove the "Sample Page" navbar (header) link, all I need to do is remove or set the page visibility to "Private". You can do that like this:

Pages -> *Select Specific Page that comes up as navbar (header) link, in my case "Sample Page".
Then..
Press "Move to Trash" button. OR simply click "Public" next to where it says "Visibility" and then select "Private" from the drop-down. Make sure you save the changes to the page as per the usual page editing process.

I hope this helps you with your quest. And if this does not quite help you with what you were trying to achieve, please do add a screenshot so I can get a better idea of what you are looking to accomplish.

Cheers!
Arty